# How to exclude unusable IP addresses from DNS query results?

Tags: c, linux, networking, dns, posix

```
root@home:~$ dig baidu.com

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;baidu.com.                     IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
baidu.com.              0       IN      A       220.181.38.251
baidu.com.              0       IN      A       220.181.38.148
ns7.baidu.com.          0       IN      A       180.76.76.92
ns3.baidu.com.          0       IN      A       112.80.248.64
ns2.baidu.com.          0       IN      A       220.181.33.31
ns4.baidu.com.          0       IN      A       14.215.178.80
```

`curl http://baidu.com` or `curl http://220.181.38.251` outputs the HTTP response info as expected:

```
<html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://www.baidu.com/">
</html>
```

However, `curl http://ns7.baidu.com` or `curl http://180.76.76.92` outputs **NOTHING!**

So, I cannot use the IP addresses of `ns*.baidu.com` to connect to `baidu.com`. More sadly, the POSIX function `getaddrinfo` querying baidu.com returns the same IP list as those in the **ANSWER SECTION** above.

**Is there a way to exclude the IP addresses of** `ns*.baidu.com` **from the results of** `getaddrinfo`**?**

**=== UPDATE ===**

It seems like a bug of WSL2's DNS server.

If I change the nameserver from the default `172.29.32.1` to `8.8.8.8`, all work well as expected.

Comment: `nsX.baidu.com` are the nameservers for the domain, not an address of `baidu.com` itself. You shouldn't use them in `curl`.

Comment: They shouldn't be in the Answer Section, they should be in the Additional Section.

Comment: @Barmar getaddrinfo cannot exclude nameserver ip addresses.

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` shouldn't be returning them in the first place.

Comment: @Barmar It actually returns them in my code.

Comment: You miss an important part of `dig` output: which (broken) nameserver did send you this? A query on `1.1.1.1` , `8.8.8.8` or `9.9.9.9` show proper reply with only `baidu.com` `A` records in the ANSWER section, as expected and mandated by DNS specifications. So the output you show is broken. If you can't use any other nameserver that is more correct, you will have to do some filtering in your own code. Or use other libraries to do DNS queries, like `getdnsapi` or similar that may allow finer filtering/query options.

Comment: I can't reproduce this result, either.

Comment: It seems a bug of WSL2's DNS server. @Barmar